# How can i put condition of maintenance mode in index file or Bootstap file in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, maintenance

> How can i put condition of maintenance mode in index file or Bootstap
>   file in magento 2 ?

I want to check if Maintenance mode i enable or disable conditional base.

How can i check that in **Index.php** file or **Bootstrap.php** file in Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this code :

```
<?php

error_reporting(1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$instance = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$maintenanceMode = $instance ->get('\Magento\Framework\App\MaintenanceMode');
$flag = $maintenanceMode->isOn();
```

It maybe helpful for you.

Comment: Is it index.php file @rohan ?

Comment: Please check my answer with code. You can use it in index.php

Comment: Yes. You can use in root file.

Comment: Thanks man :) it's working file !! (3 mins to accept as answer :D)

Comment: Happy to help :) Happy Coding !!

Answer (score 2):

If **var/.maintenance.flag** file does not exist, Magento operates normally, and maintenance mode is off. If it exists, maintenance mode is on. So you can write code for the same.

```
$objManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$maintenanceMode = $objManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\MaintenanceMode');
$flag = $maintenanceMode->isOn();
```

Answer (score 2):

Put below code in your index.php file

```
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$maintenanceMode = $obj ->get('\Magento\Framework\App\MaintenanceMode');
$flag = $maintenanceMode->set(1);
```